# How to get the content from Twilio response message

Tags: java, spring-mvc, twilio

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"sms"},method = RequestMethod.POST)
public string rplyMessage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    Body body = new Body.Builder("Response message").build();
Message sms =
        new Message.Builder().body(body).build();

MessagingResponse twiml = new MessagingResponse.Builder().message(sms).build();

response.setContentType("application/xml");

try {
    response.getWriter().print(twiml.toXml());
} catch (TwiMLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

This is how I handle the twilio response message.I want to get the content from the response message. and i want to store it in the database.How I can get the content from the response message.

Comment: you just want to save the XML in database?

Comment: I want to get the sender 4n number and the response message body and store in the database.

Comment: there are many different databases, it's too broad

Comment: Can you tell me how to get the message content and senders number only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When [Twilio makes a request to your application](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request) it sends the parameters encoded as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in the body of the POST request.

I've never written Java Spring MVC before, so excuse me if this isn't spot on, but I believe you can then read those parameters out of the body using the `@RequestParam` annotation.

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"sms"},method = RequestMethod.POST)
public string rplyMessage(
    HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response,
    @RequestParam("Body") String message,
    @RequestParam("From") String from
) throws IOException {
    storeMessage(from, message);

    // respond to the request
}
```

The message body and the number that sent it are the parameters "Body" and "From", you can see [all the available request parameters here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request#request-parameters). So, for example with the message, you set the argument to `@RequestParam` to the name of the parameter, then you set the type and what you want the variable to be called within the method, thus: `@RequestParam("Body") String message`.

I don't know how you plan to use the database, but that's what I can tell you. You can read more about [`@RequestParam` here](http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/spring-mvc-request-param/) and see some [Twilio Java and Spring tutorials here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials?order_by=-popularity_rank&filter-language=java).

Let me know if that helps at all.